Is there any good way to convert StartActivityResult callback in compose to Coroutine linear style?
I'm facing a design problem about compose + coroutine.
Let's say I got a compose button and after I click it I need to startActivityResult to another app, and execute callback after I got result from it.
The most important part is I want it in a linear style like using suspendCancellableCoroutine.
I know how to deal with it in not-compose case like this:
private var mContinuation:Continuation<Boolean>? = null

private val launcher = launcherRegister(
    onResult = {result ->
        mContinuation?.resume(result)
    }
)

private fun launcherRegister(
    onResult: (Boolean) -> Unit,
) = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ activityResult: ActivityResult ->
    onResult(activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
}

override fun onCreateView(...):View{
    //...
    textView.setOnClickListener {
        goo(
            onPostExecute = { Log.d("Timothy", "onPostExecute")},
            onPreExecute = { Log.d("Timothy", "onPreExecute")},
            onSuccess = {Log.d("Timothy","onSuccess")},
            scope = lifecycleScope,
            intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)
        )
    }
    //...
}


suspend fun foo(intent:Intent):Boolean = suspendCancellableCoroutine{cont->
    mContinuation = cont
    cont.invokeOnCancellation{
        launcher.unregister()
        mContinuation = null
    }
    launcher.launch(intent)
}

fun goo(
    onPreExecute: () -> Unit,
    onPostExecute: () -> Unit,
    onSuccess: () -> Unit,
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    intent: Intent
){
    scope.launch {
        withTimeout(10_000){
            onPreExecute()
            val success = foo(intent)
            if(success){
                onSuccess()
            }
            onPostExecute()
        }
    }
}

But I got stuck in rememberLauncherForActivityResult of compose.
suspendCancellableCoroutine need to do with suspend modifier and composable function shouldn't be suspend.
I'm wondering to know is there any good way to get activity result from another app in compose scope and do it in linear style?
Thanks.
[2024-05-10 update]
Thanks for reminding of @JanBína. The code I provide before is so wrong. From the docs:

"This must be called unconditionally, as part of initialization path,
typically as a field initializer of an Activity or Fragment."

I update the second version.

Your non-compose example is wrong though, you cannot call registerForActivityResult after you click the button as your example assumes. From the docs: "This must be called unconditionally, as part of initialization path, typically as a field initializer of an Activity or Fragment."

@JanBína  Ohh... you're right . I totally forgot this. I will update my question. Thanks !

The updated code is not right either. The reason that registerForActivityResult has to be called unconditionally is that your activity could be recreated while user is in that other activity you launched. In that case, your original mContinuation will be discarded and set back to null. registerForActivityResult will be called again, and onResult will be called, but since mContinuation is null, you won't handle it. You shouldn't fight the api... What is the reason for you to wont it "linear" - is it just preference, or is there something you cannot do without it?

@JanBína Thanks for your response. I know my updated code is sort of risky. And it is just a opening question. I just want to know is there any solution to convert this callback style into linear just like other case go with suspendCancellableCoroutine. I think it's more readble and easy to maintain.
